# Kml placemarks list with Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I would like to know if there is a way to display the Placemarks of a kml hosted online using the Google Maps API. What I would like to do is to have a panel to navigate the folders like the one provided by google maps when I search for an online KML -> https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&hl=en&q=http://kmlscribe.googlepages.com/SamplesInMaps.kml

I don't have any problem to display only the KML using the API, this is the code I have:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src= "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script>
var map;
var cta_layer;

function initialize() {
    var kmlUrl = 'http://kmlscribe.googlepages.com/SamplesInMaps.kml';
    var myOptions = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    cta_layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, {suppressInfoWindows: false,preserveViewport:false});
    cta_layer.setMap(map);
}
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas"  style="height: 800px;width: 800px;">
    </div>
</body>
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the third party parsers for KML.  [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) has the best "sidebar" support.  You can also use [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/), but you have to build the sidebar yourself.

Notes:

1. both these third-party parsers parse the KML in the browser and render the it using native Google Maps API v3 objects, so they may have performance issues for complex KML.
2. if the KML is hosted in a different domain from the web page, they require proxies to access the KML (due to the same domain restriction on XmlHttpRequest)

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_dyasdesigns_com_geoxml_mtrmtrip3.html)